# jQuery Attribute selector with a period

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use a jQuery selector that finds all input fields with a specific name:

```
$('input[name=Filter']).click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

This should match the following items:

```
<input type="radio" name="Filter" value="A" />
<input type="radio" name="Filter" value="B" />
```

This is working fine. The problem I am having is that my names are dynamically generated by ASP.net MVC and the names have a period:

```
<input type="radio" name="Parent.Filter" value="A" />
<input type="radio" name="Parent.Filter" value="B" />
```

I tried to write the following selector:

```
$('input[name=Parent.Filter]').click(function() {
});
```

I am getting the following error: 
`Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=Parent.Filter]`

How can I write this expression so that it works properly?

Comment: not sure if will work but try... `$('input[name="Parent.Filter"]')`

Comment: Have you tried `'input[name*="Filter"]'`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quotes are mandatory, and in this instance it won't work without them.

```
$('input[name="Parent.Filter"]').click(function() {
});
```

[From the API reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> **value**    An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPhGQ/) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2):

This works, you just need "" around the name:

```
$('input[name="Parent.Filter"]').click(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment to the question I can confirm that this does work...

```
$('input[name="Parent.Filter"]').click(function() {
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/TRrq7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("input[name='Parent.Filter']")`